# Uploading byte array to WCF server

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, image-uploading

I am unable to post image in windows phone which is converted into array of byte,here is mycode-

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += dataSubmitCompleted;
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(
    "here url/Service1.svc/saverecord3" + convertImageToArray(bitmapImage1),
    UriKind.Absolute));
```

here convertImageToArray is method which convert photo to byte array

Comment: do you mean UploadStringAsync

Comment: Why don't you create a client by creating a service reference in your project? Trying to handle it yourself through the url is hacky at best.

Comment: i am making wcf service that will generic for windows phone,i-phone etc,any one can use url to upload,that's why i am not adding service reference in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't submit an image in a GET request, which is what `DownloadStringAsync` does. As @radoslaf mentioned, you should use an *Upload* method instead (which does a POST, by default). And if you're sending a byte array, you should use `UploadDataAsync` (not `UploadString`).

You should also code your service to receive bytes from the client. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx shows how you can implement such a service.

*Update after comment* - I see, the WebClient API for WP7.5 is really very limited. For this scenario, you're likely better using the `HttpWebRequest` type. The code below shows how this can be used for your scenario.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://here.url/service1.svc/saverecord3");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/octet-stream";
        req.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCompleted, req);
    }

    void GetRequestStreamCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        Stream reqStream = req.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
        reqStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
        req.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCompleted, req);
    }

    void GetResponseCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text = "Upload result: " + resp.StatusCode;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks carlosfigueria,but i am working with windows phone and there is no method of UploadDataAsync in WebClient class.Only available method are-DownloadStringAsync,OpenReadAsync,OpenWriteAsync and UploadStringAsync .Which one is useful for me.